# JSDOC: Override typedef object property

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I'm trying to document query string types on a request's `param` object. I have a `Request` type for the request @param but I want to be able to override its inherited `param` object because every request function may have a different set of query strings.

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Request
 * @property {Object} params - Object that contains parameters passed to a route. (Query strings).
 * @property {string} hostname - Hostname from the HTTP-request.
 */

 class ProfileController extends Controller {
    /**
     * Fetch a profile
     * @param {Request} req - Request object
     * @param {string} req.params.id - Node ID <-- I WANT TO DO THIS, THIS DOESNT WORK
     * @param {Object} res - Response
     */
   get = (req, res) => {
    const { id, hostname } = req.params;
    // req.params.id doesn't get intellisense
   };
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} Request
 * @property {Object} params - Object that contains parameters passed to a route. (Query strings).
 * @property {string} hostname - Hostname from the HTTP-request.
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyRequest
 * @property {Object} params - Object that contains parameters passed to a route. (Query strings).
 * @property {string} params.id - Node ID
 */

class ProfileController extends Controller {
  /**
   * Fetch a profile
   * @param {Request & MyRequest} req - Request object
   * @param {Object} res - Response
   */
  get (req, res) {
    const { id, otherParam } = req.params;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't get intellisense on `req.params.id`, is it possible to get that somehow?